# jquery priority execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me with this:

```
$('#n').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().append('<a href="javascript:void()">&nbsp;delete</a>');
    $(this).next().click(function() {
        alert('clicked'); //this not working
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        $(this).next().remove();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkun9/); the problem is that the  `blur()` event is executed before `click()` event.

Comment: You should be careful with that click event though. A delete button is appended as many times as I click the textbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a timeout to postpone the removal for some milliseconds.

example : http://jsfiddle.net/vkun9/7/

```
$(this).blur(function() {
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function(){$(_this).next().remove();},100);
        });
```

I also moved the `blur` attaching to be outside of the click handler, as it was adding an additional one each time the element was clicked, and changed the click handler to the focus to avoid multiple `remove` buttons from repeated clicking on the input, as @dheerosaur noted.

so

```
$('#n')
    .focus(function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<a href="javascript:void()">&nbsp;delete</a>');
        $(this).next().click(function() {
            alert('clicked'); //this not working
        });
    })
    .blur(function() {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function(){$(_this).next().remove();},100);
    });
```

What you experience, though, is not a problem. It is the normal behaviour, as the element need to lose focus (*fires the blur*) before another element can have it.

You should also match the label `for` attribute with the id of the input element.

Comment: Doesn't work very well if you tab away from the input to the delete link. The delete link will vanish on you before you can "click" it with your keyboard.

Comment: @Petersen, indeed. I was only answering to the specific pronlem. But you are very correct that keyboard-users should also be handled.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [outside events plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) and you can do something like this:

```
$('.input_field input').focus(function() {
    var div = $(this).parent();
    var link = $('<a href="#">delete</a>').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked');
    }).appendTo(div);
    $(this).data('delete', link);
}).bind('focusoutside clickoutside', function(e) {
    var link = $(this).data('delete');
    if (link && e.target != link[0]) {
        link.remove();
    }
});
```

First switch to using the focus event rather than the click event on your input field, some people actually use the keyboard to navigate through form fields ;-).

Then its creating the delete link, adding it to the page and storing a reference to it in on the input field.

Then with the outside event plugin we can bind focusoutside and clickoutside which get triggered when the user tabs or clicks outside the input field.  By checking of the target of the event was the delete link or not we can tell if we should remove the link.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/vkun9/6/

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting a very short timeout in the blur event. this worked for me.

```
    $(this).blur(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){$(this).next().remove();}, 1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `blur()` I put together a [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)-based approach, though it does have a slightly clunky `if`/`else` statement:

```
$('.input_field').hover(
    function(){
        if ($(this).find('.delete').length) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('<a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>')
            .appendTo($(this));
        }
    },
    function(){
        if ($('#n').is(':focus')){
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.delete').remove();
        }
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vkun9/4/).

This approach does, however, ensure that there's only *one* delete link appended to the `input_field` (rather than the multiple links appended if the `input` is clicked multiple times in your original demo).

Comment: Doesn't handle those of us that use the tab key to move from one element/input to another.

Comment: @PetersenDidIt, that's absolutely true...I'll try and edit to fix that (+1 for reminding me of non-mouse-using folks) =)