# The simplest solution to hide calendar on blur or click

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/SXrAb/

Following the jsfiddle link there is a simplified sample of what I need. Currently it shows the calendar on button click, and hides it on input blur.

What I cannot implement additionally is hiding calendar on button click.

So - calendar should:

1. <strike>open on button click if hidden</strike> (done)
2. <strike>hide on blur</strike> (done)
3. hide on button click if opened (this is what I'm in stuck with, because blur is triggered before button click event so I have no chance to handle it properly)

**UPD**:

the solution is expected to work correctly in all cases, like "mousedown on button, drag below, mouseup" (otherwise I wouldn't ask it ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451115/jquery-priority-execution ; I am writing a jsfiddle now :) hope this link helps, cheers!

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: give a focus to input, press button, press tab

Comment: @Tats_innit: hehe, yes, timeouts is another thing I'd like to avoid, but let's see ;-)

Comment: @zerkms lmao :D - you were right settimeout is bad as... (experience talks) try this please: http://jsfiddle.net/SXrAb/50/ If it does work according to your need should I set it as one of the answer as well? Cheers!

Comment: @Tats_innit: you should it put as an answer anyway, I respect even attempt

Comment: @zerkms you are legend mate! :) cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar');
var mousedown = false;

$('#calendar-input').blur(function() {
    if (!mousedown)
        $calendar.hide();
});

$('#calendar-button').mousedown(function() {
    mousedown = true;
});

$('#calendar-button').mouseup(function() {
    mousedown = false;
});

$('#calendar-button').click(function() {
    if ($calendar.is(':visible')) {
         $calendar.hide();
    }
    else {
        $calendar.show();
        $('#calendar-input').focus();
    }
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tz73k/

UPDATE: OK, I moved the mouseup event to the document level.  I don't think the mouse state can be tricked now by dragging the mouse before releasing it:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar');
var mousedown = false;

$('#calendar-input').blur(function() {
    if (!mousedown)
        $calendar.hide();
});

$('#calendar-button').mousedown(function() {
    mousedown = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    mousedown = false;
});

$('#calendar-button').click(function() {
    if ($calendar.is(':visible')) {
         $calendar.hide();
    }
    else {
        $calendar.show();
        $('#calendar-input').focus();
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQ5CT/

Comment: Yep, I implemented something similar, but it still can be fooled in an easy way: 1. press button 2. mouse down on button, drag below (out of the button), release mouse button 3. give a focus to input 4. press tab. And the calendar is not hidden, because `mousedown` flag is in `true`

Comment: Ahhhh yes.  My argument is invalid.

Comment: @zerkms I moved the mouseup event to the document level... I'm hoping it cannot be tricked now by mouse dragging.  See my updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **Demo here** http://jsfiddle.net/SXrAb/50/ -- (non alert version) http://jsfiddle.net/SXrAb/51/

Thanks zerkms!

**JQuery Code**

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar');
$calendar.hide();

var isBlurEventInvoked = true;
var calendarShow = false;

$('#calendar-input').blur(function() {
    alert(isBlurEventInvoked + " ==== " + calendarShow);
    if (isBlurEventInvoked && calendarShow){
        $calendar.hide();
        isBlurEventInvoked = true;
    } 

});

$('#calendar-button').click(function() {

    if (!$calendar.is(':visible') && isBlurEventInvoked){
       $calendar.show();
       $('#calendar-input').focus();
       calendarShow =  true;
       isBlurEventInvoked = true;
    }else if ($calendar.is(':visible')) {
        $calendar.hide();
        isBlurEventInvoked = false;
        calendarShow = false;
    }

});


​
```

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to think of the calendar and the button as a set, where you only hide the calendar when everything in the set has blurred. To do this you need a system where focus can be "handed off" between the calendar and button without triggering your hide function. To do this you'll need a focus and blur handler on both your calendar and your button, as well as a state variable for isFocused.

```
var isFocused;

jQuery('#calendar,#calendar-button,#calendar-input').blur(function(){
  isFocused = false;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!isFocused) { hide(); }
  }, 0);
});

jQuery('#calendar,#calendar-button,#calendar-input').focus(function(){
  isFocused = true;
});
```

The setTimeout is because, when you click the button, focus is lost on calendar before it's gained on the button, so there's momentarily nothing in focus.

**Edit**

I guess there's actually three elements in the set, the button, the textbox, and the calendar. I updated the example. This also fixes the issue that, in your example, you can't click between the calendar and the textbox without the calendar hiding. Presumably the real calendar can be manipulated by clicking it.

**Edit 2**

For this to work you'll need to make your calendar focusable by giving it a tabindex.

```
<span id="calendar" tabindex="-1">I'm a calendar ;-)</span>
```

Comment: Yep, that (by saying that I mean the order of "blur-click-0timeout") works de-facto. But is it guaranteed by any standard?